# Отображение кириллицы

Tags: visual-studio-code, шрифты

Установил новый шрифт для редактора и появился вопрос : кириллица из-за шрифта так отображается или нужно прописать какой-то параметр ? 
Шрифт : MonoLisa 
Или нужен отдельный шрифт под кириллицу ? хм...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, из-за шрифта. Вы в настройках указали только новый шрифт вместо старых, или дописали его в начало существующего списка шрифтов?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat только новый, а можно ли отдельно задать шрифт для кириллицы, чтобы по итогу было 2 шрифта ?

Comment: Попробуйте через запятую написать шрифт для кириллицы.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat не работает (